# MYSQL - Cannot able to drop a column

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL 5.1. When i try to drop a column in a table, it throws the following error.
MATERIAL_OUTWARD_ID is a foreign key.

Query:

```
alter table `tispa`.`customer_invoice` drop `MATERIAL_OUTWARD_ID`
```

Error:

```
Error on rename of '.\tispa\#sql-78_8' to '.\tispa\customer_invoice' (errno: 150)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it.

First drop the foreign key like

```
alter table `tispa`.`customer_invoice` drop foreign key  `FK_material_out_id` ;
```

Then drop the column like

```
alter table `tispa`.`customer_invoice` drop `MATERIAL_OUTWARD_ID`;
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

try dropping the foreign key?

```
alter table 
...
DROP FOREIGN KEY MATERIAL_OUTWARD_ID
```